# Newsletter subscription?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I have received an e-mail message asking to confirm my e-mail address for a newsletter subscription.  I do not want a newsletter subscription.  I have two questions:

1. What might I have clicked inadvertently to sign up for the newsletter?
2. How can I unsubscribe from it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a newsletter subscription section in your profile Preferences:

[image: Profile newsletter preference]

Find it and see if you have ticked the box (by mistake or otherwise).

Another way to subscribe to the newsletter is to click on the ad on the homepage:

[image: newsletter ad homepage]

Maybe you did this inadvertedly.

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't noticed the "tabs" on the profile page (specifically the "edit profile and settings" tab), much less the "preferences" section.

Comment: @phoog *cough cough* 27k rep user *cough cough* :P

Comment: Um, having written the occasional popular answer to some questions does not imply that I spend any significant amount of time in the profile section.  Why would I do that?  I use it only occasionally to find comments I've posted.  I can't imagine that I clicked that checkbox by accident; I certainly don't recall ever having been in the "edit profile and settings" area before.

Comment: @phoog You maybe clicked on the homepage ad by mistake.

Comment: That seems much more likely!  I also didn't notice it, but the touchpad on my computer often registers a click when I'm just moving the mouse pointer around.  Thanks.